# .NET forms - disabled control missing events

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a disabled from element and I want to enable it on double-click.

The problem is the `DoubleClick` handler only gets called when `Foo.Enabled = True`. When it's disabled, the handler doesn't received the double-click event.

```
this.Foo.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Foo_OnDoubleClick);

// Handler
private void Foo_OnDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Double click");
}
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: That's to be expected. It's .. disabled.

Comment: That's not possible.  Setting Enabled = false means exactly what you found out it means.  All input events are disabled.

Comment: As a workaround/hack - What if it was Enabled but "looked Disabled"?

Comment: @user2864740 I still want to prevent users from entering a value when it is disabled.

Comment: just fake it, get the rectangle coords of the disabled button and handle the click events of the container `if(mouse in button area) tada!`

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, Windows forms.

Comment: @RadioSpace Now *I* would accept that as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own control inheriting from its base control (FOO) and override the `Enable` behavior. That way you will be able to make it behave the way that you wish.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public class MyControl : Button //Example control
{
    //Override and/or implement what you need in this control

    public MyControl()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you wish to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I can also receive events by overriding `OnDoubleClick` method.

Comment: Yes, you can. You should be able to "design" the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> I still want to prevent users from entering a value when it is disabled.

Your question makes it sounds like you want to apply this to *any* control, but then your comment makes it sounds like you want to apply it to a `TextBox`.

If the latter case is true, set the `TextBox.ReadOnly` property to `True` instead of disabling the control.

Users will not be able to edit the value, but the double-click event will still fire.

Answer (score 0):

You Should handle mouse double click event of Parent(all double click goes to Enabled parent) then by check mouse location returned by event against each disabled control rectangle you can determine which control has been clicked.